# How to judge the color of UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

```
UILabel *templabel = [self.wallBoxArray objectAtIndex:i];

for( int i = 0 ; i < [self.wallBoxArray count]; i++)
{
  if(templabel.backgroundColor == [UIColor greenColor])
   {
     NSLog(@"the color isn green");  
   }
}
```

There are many label's in my array. They all initialized with green color. But i judged that way ,why cant print " the color isn't green.

Comment: I have noticed that you have been making edits to place the answer into the question itself. This is not nessisary;  if you have an answer then provide it as an answer, if someone else answers your question and it is the most useful mark it as correct using the green checkmark

Comment: @RichardTingle Hey richard, you know my account was forbidden to ask questions any more. Although i have read the "Help" center, but i still can't find the reasons why. I tried to make my old questions and answers more clearly. Could you help me on this? Thanks very much!

Comment: looking at your profile;  it must be from deleted questions.  Have a lot of your questions been deleted?

Comment: @RichardTingle I do deleted some low quality questions(not much), but i can't find them. After some search i found "all of which are only visible to moderators". I only find a " deleted recent questions" under "Questions" tab. But there's no delete questions. How should i find them? Thank you very much Richard, i am not a English speaker, so i may missed some necessary information. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The deleted link only shows recently deleted questions.  You could flag any of your own questions under "other" and explain you would like access to your deleted questions so you can improve them to escape a question ban

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UIColor class cluster implements `-isEqual:`, so you could just use

```
if([templabel.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor greenColor]])
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a pointer comparision there, so if the color's are both green, but different instances of UIColor, this will fail.   And they are because UIView's backgroundColor property is a copy property.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor
```

I'm sort of surprised this is that convoluted, but to check for equality, try the following:

```
CGColorEqualToColor([templabel.backgroundColor CGColor], [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor])
```

This is checking equality of the color value, not just a pointer comparison.   Also remember to do `[str compare:otherString] == NSOrderSame` when checking strings!

Comment: Or `[str isEqualToString:otherString]`.